# HTML5 article tag: pre article content?

Tags: css, html, accessibility, semantic-markup

My question is probably based on a bad design. However, I can't change that and need to work with it. This is the visual draft I'm talking about, it's just a part of a full website:

[image: Test]

As you can see there's a title of an article with a background image, then a breadcrumb toolbar and finally, the articles content. Now, usually, if there wouldn't be the breadcrumb toolbar you could simply wrap it into an `<article>`. But the breadcrumb divides the article in a "pre" article and a main article part. The only "clean" HTML5 way would be to wrap the article including the header with background image into an `<article>` and position the breadcrumb into the target visual position. However, I'm classifying this as "hack" and I'm searching a better way.

**What would be the preferred markup for this scenario?**

Comment: Your best bet is probably to just avoid the use of <article> or <main> altogether, and treat the entire HTML document as the article. Yes the breadcrumb <nav> will still be part of the document outline along with the article content, but it beats putting the <nav> in an <article>.

Comment: If this is part of a page with potentially multiple articles with their own breadcrumbs dividing their headers and content... then I would settle for the CSS workaround.

Comment: The CSS workaround (having the breadcrumb outside the article and still position it into the article with CSS) is my workaround too, until there's a better solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There won't be any perfect the solution for the current requirement.**

As pointed out by comments to the previous answer, the `nav` is not related to the article.

Also, WCAG instructs that :

> 1.3.2 [Meaningful Sequence](https://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/content-structure-separation-sequence.html): When the sequence in which content is presented affects its meaning, a correct reading sequence can be programmatically determined. (Level A)

*EDIT : If changing the order of the element can preserve a meaningful sequence ([G57](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/2016/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20160105/G57)), when the elements does not match visually the DOM order ([see C27](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/2016/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20160105/C27)) the visual focus indicator of the screen reader will not match the standard reading order which will result in bad UX for people with low vision using a screenreader.*

So it's impossible to try a CSS visual hack to invert the order between the elements visually without breaking another rule.

You may think of a third technique :

- set `aria-hidden` on the visible title,
- use `aria-labelledby` on the `article` tag to point to the `h1` outside the `article` element :

For instance:

```
 <header>
     <h1 aria-hidden="true" id="title">Your title</h1>
     <nav><!-- nav here --></nav>
 </header>

 <article aria-labelledby="title">
     // article here
 </article>
```

Another way to do is to duplicate the title element, one visible, one for assistive technology

```
 <header>
     <div aria-hidden="true">Your title</div>
     <nav><!-- nav here --></nav>
 </header>

 <article>
     <h1 class="sr-only">Your title</h1>
     // article here
 </article>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but can you elaborate the quote (`When the sequence in which content is presented affects its meaning, a correct reading sequence can be programmatically determined. (Level A)`)? I don't fully understand the meaning behind it. One more question: Your solution hides the h1 for screen readers (labelledby doesn't repesent the heading order). In my eyes this would be a bad workaround too, since screen readers can't access the heading with the heading shortcuts on the keyboard?!

Comment: @dude I edited my answer, I might have been too affirmative for this case, as we can consider that your content is still meaningful. I added another solution, but that still is a makeshift (I personnaly hate using those "sr-only" css classes)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. The example of tab order makes sense. I'll wait a few days for another answer, if there's no one I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It could be something like this -

```
<article>
    <header>
        //APPLY BACKGROUND IMAGE
        <h1>YOUR TITLE</h1>
    </header>

    <nav>
        //USE BREADCRUMBS HERE
    </nav>

    <section>
        //USE THIS FOR CONTENT
    </section>
</article>
```

Comment: But then the article would contain content (nav) that is not related to the article

Comment: There is no problem in placing <nav> inside <article>

Comment: @RudrakshPathak: Depends what you mean with "problem". dude is right, content inside of `article` has to be related to the article, but the breadcrumbs `nav` is related to the page, not specifically to the article. A `nav` element inside of `article` would make sense if it’s the navigation *for that article* (e.g., a table of contents, or pagination, etc.). -- However, you could argue that the breadcrumbs are some kind of "category" under which the article is categorized, but then using `nav` wouldn’t necessarily make sense.

Comment: As my example image shows, the nav I'm talking about is almost equal in all pages. Only the links vary on each page. Therefore it's not related to the article itself.

Comment: Hi @unor, You are making a good point. So what do you suggest, what should we do here ?

Comment: @RudrakshPathak: I don’t have a good solution for OP’s constraints :) I’d say this should be solved in CSS.